# Has anyone integrated Stratosource and Jenkins for continuous integration?

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

So I have a current CI setup that enables me to pull metadata from Salesforce org(using Jenkins + Ant migration tool), push it to git, create a package out of it and then re-deploy this package to another Salesforce org.

I have been hearing good things about Stratosource, and would like to know if anyone has managed to integrate Stratosource with Jenkins as part of Continuous Integration cycle.

If so, could someone please provide a few pointers?

I have tried searching but there doesn't seem to be much documentation on this topic.

Comment: I have seen aticles related to Jenkins and Git .I guess you can take some infor from those and start your own